# Name of the user who has processed the cube

Tags: ssas, cube

There is a code piece in which I have to get the username of the user who has processed the cube or has made any changes in the cube structure.

I have searched in the `SSAS` DMV's, but didn't find what I needed; I only found the last processed time, but not the name of the user.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can track this using an Extended Event.  Add the ProgressReportBegin and ProgressReportEnd events which are for processing.  These events include the NTUserName and StartTime fields which you can use to find who processed the cube and when.  The Extended Event will need to be running when the cube is processed to capture this.  The following is an example XMLA command which can be run when connected to your SSAS database in SSMS to create an Extended Event that tracks cube processing and outputs the results to a file.  Of course many of these options are just defaults and you may want to make adjustments as necessary.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/instances/monitor-analysis-services-with-sql-server-extended-events?view=sql-server-2017

```
<Create xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
  <ObjectDefinition>
    <Trace>
      <ID>XE_Cube_Process</ID>
      <Name>XE_Cube_Process</Name>
      <XEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2011/engine/300/300">
        <event_session name="XE_Cube_Process" dispatchLatency="0" maxEventSize="0" maxMemory="4" memoryPartition="none" eventRetentionMode="AllowSingleEventLoss" trackCausality="true" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
          <event package="AS" name="ProgressReportEnd" />
          <event package="AS" name="ProgressReportBegin" />
          <target package="package0" name="event_file">
            <parameter name="filename" value="C:\Test\XE_Cube_Process.xel" />
            <parameter name="max_file_size" value="4096" />
            <parameter name="max_rollover_files" value="10" />
            <parameter name="increment" value="1024" />
          </target>
        </event_session>
      </XEvent>
    </Trace>
  </ObjectDefinition>
</Create>
```

Comment: thank you for your reply , is there any sql table where i can see this information.